# How to add Page title in a Custom Page Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have set page title in my custom controller like below

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__("My Custom Page");
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

This displays the title with the title suffix configured in `Content->Design->Configuration->Theme edit->HTML Head->Title Suffix`

I need to remove title suffix. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you create any layout xml for this page or its a simple cms page?

Comment: Use this "$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Brands'));" to set title

Comment: @sukumar Gorai. Yes i have created a layout.xml for it.

Comment: @Dharmendra Jadav. using prepend also adds suffix to the title.  I am saying about browser tab title...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can page title from layout xml like below:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <action method="setPageTitle">
        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Custom Page</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

You need to add this blog to your layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for it

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        PageFactory $pageFactory,

        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;

        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {        


        $pageFactory = $this->_pageFactory->create();

        // Add title which is got by the configuration via backend
        $pageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(
           'Custom Page Title'
        );


        return $pageFactory;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method prepend(__("My Title")); in your controller.

```
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__("Your Title"));
        return $resultPage;
}
```